# Python - value from a function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and this my first time using functions. I made a while loop to make sure that the user's input is an int and not a string but when I enter a number it still continues the while loop.

```
import time
numList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
loop = 1


def checkIfBetween09(n):
    if (n in numList):
        print('Number is between 0 and 9 ')
    else:
        print('Number is not between 0 and 9 ')


def checkIfInt(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
        print('thats a number')
        loop = 0
        return (loop)
    except:
        print('What you typed was not a number')


while (loop == 1):
    fib_int1 = input('Type in a number from 0 to 9 - ')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    checkIfInt(fib_int1)
    time.sleep(0.5)

int(fib_int1)
checkIfBetween09(fib_int1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your function is that while you return `loop` in `checkIfInt`, you do not assign it to anything in your while loop. You need to replace

```
checkIfInt(x)
```

with

```
loop = checkIfInt(x)
```

However, this also means that `checkIfInt` should return 1 if the `except` statement is used, otherwise the function will return `None` and the loop will exit (`None != 1`).

```
except:
  print('What you typed was not a number')
  return(1)
```

Note: in general, it may be helpful to use `True/False` in while loops rather than `1/0` since it is clearer what you are trying to signal (an integer is entered and the loop is broken vs otherwise).
Additionally, you can also check types with `type(fib_int1) == int` although that will not verify it is between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the below code at the end of your while loop

loop =+ 1

OR

loop = loop + 1

Comment: When I add loop = loop + 1 at the end of the while loop it ends the loop which is great but the problem is that then it wouldn't repeat if the user's input wasn't an int and when I try putting it in the function it doesn't save the value and just sets the value back to 1

Comment: You need to change your while condition to  while True:
    fib_int1 = input('Type in a number from 0 to 9 - ')
    checkIfInt(fib_int1)
    loop =+ 1